# How to add panel to 3D view Tool shelf in Texture Paint Mode

Tags: python, scripting

I'm just trying to to get my addon panel to show up in the tool shelf in Texture Paint mode, but I can't figure out the correct 'bl_' combination to make it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use this

```
bl_<prop>      | allowed
---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------
bl_space_type  | 'CLIP_EDITOR', 'CONSOLE', 'DOPESHEET_EDITOR', 'EMPTY',
               | 'FILE_BROWSER', 'GRAPH_EDITOR', 'IMAGE_EDITOR', 'INFO',
               | 'LOGIC_EDITOR', 'NLA_EDITOR', 'NODE_EDITOR', 'OUTLINER',
               | 'PROPERTIES', 'SEQUENCE_EDITOR', 'TEXT_EDITOR', 'TIMELINE',
               | 'USER_PREFERENCES', 'VIEW_3D'
---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------
bl_region_type | 'CHANNELS', 'HEADER', 'PREVIEW', 'TEMPORARY', 'TOOLS',
               | 'TOOL_PROPS', 'UI', 'WINDOW'
---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------
bl_context     | 'armature_edit', 'curve_edit', 'imagepaint', 'lattice_edit',
               | 'mball_edit', 'mesh_edit', 'objectmode', 'particlemode',
               | 'posemode', 'sculpt_mode', 'surface_edit', 'text_edit',
               | 'vertexpaint', 'weightpaint'
```

So for you I think it's:

```
bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'
bl_context = "imagepaint"
```

Comment: Thanks! Where did you find that?

Comment: assembled from documentation  https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Header.html?highlight=bl_space_type#bpy.types.Header.bl_space_type   etc -- literally just adding the `bl_<kind>` to the search

Comment: Ah, my search was too specific then.